# Find simiarities between two text files

Tags: text, compare

I NEED to a find a solution for the following,

```
File A:    
a
b
c


File B: 
a
b
c
d
```

I need a script to tell say that Contents of `File A` is present in `File B`. (Script or tool) 
Thank for all responses and help.

Comment: Do you need a script or some software is enough?

Comment: A script would be the best. I am currently using beyond compare but it only output differences. I need to know whether all contents of File A is present in File B. Thanks